# Excluir rangos IP según su terminación

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un listado de IP's y me gustaría excluir con una consulta un cierto rango:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip_addr) FROM ipaddresses;
```

Da como resultado:

```
172.0.1.10
150.0.1.43
150.0.1.12
140.1.2.34
150.3.2.50
```

Según el caso, quiero excluir las terminaciones del 10 al 20, por lo que únicamente me aparecerían:

```
150.0.1.43
140.1.2.34
150.3.2.50
```

¿Como puedo excluir los valores que terminen desde `.10` al `.20`? Es decir, su terminación.

Comment: buenas, encontre una respuesta ingles que te podría ayudar, es utilizando ```REGEXP```, espero te sea de ayuda. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699056/how-to-match-an-ip-address-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu campo `ip_addr` es un `INT UNSIGNED` que almacena los cuatro octetos de los que está compuesta la dirección IP:

- Dirección IP: `A.B.C.D`
- Valor de `ip_addr` (ambos cálculos son equivalentes):

  - ( ( ( A * 256 + B ) * 256 + C ) * 256 ) + D
  - ( ( ( A << 8 + B ) << 8 + C ) << 8 ) + D

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#/media/File:Ipv4_address.svg]

Para obtener la última parte necesitas es calcular el [módulo `256`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) (`ip_addr MOD 256`, `ip_addr % 256` y `MOD(ip_addr, 256)` son equivalentes) o bien una [máscara binaria `Y`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) (`&`) de 255 y hacer la comprobación con el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
  ip_addr,
  INET_NTOA(ip_addr) ip
FROM ipaddresses
WHERE
  (ip_addr MOD 256) NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

O bien:

```
SELECT
  ip_addr,
  INET_NTOA(ip_addr) ip
FROM ipaddresses
WHERE
  (ip_addr & 255) NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

[Aquí tienes un ejemplo en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mCbhFgXwdCHB4D6MzyafFT/1).

---

La principal ventaja de hacer este cálculo matemático, en vez usar funciones de comparación de cadenas de caracteres, es la eficiencia.

Una operación de bits o el cálculo del resto de una división (el módulo) son operaciones con orden de ejecución constante `O(1)`.

Las comparaciones de cadenas requieren una llamada a una conversión de número a cadena y, posteriormente, la operación de comparación propiamente dicha cuya eficiencia depende de las longitudes de las cadenas a comparar y la posición de la coincidencia, pudiendo generalizar su orden a `O(N)`.

Comment: gracias por la explicación. Me sirvió!

Answer (score 1):

Usando like y comodines:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip_addr) 
FROM ipaddresses 
where INET_NTOA(ip_addr) not like '%.1_' 
and INET_NTOA(ip_addr) not like '%.2_';
```

Comment: Buena solución, te llevas mi +1, pero no deberías sobrecargar innecesariamente la consulta SQL con conversiones y comprobaciones de cadenas de caracteres si no son necesarias. Para pocos registros y un SGBD poco usado la diferencia de rendimiento no es apreciable, pero para un entorno con miles (o cientos de miles) de registros y un SGBD cargado la diferencia se hace notable.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, es verdad, aunque como siempre, depende del contexto. Si es un reporte de única vez, si tarda un poco más no suele hacer la diferencia. Sí me parece que tu solución es más performante e ingeniosa y la verdad no se me hubiera ocurrido hacerlo así. La voy a tener en cuenta si se me presenta un caso similar.